# How to determine build origin with MSBuild Script?

Tags: c#, msbuild, build-automation, msbuildextensionpack

I am using MSBuild along with [MSBuild Extensions](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) and I am looking for a way to determine what machine my build is being conducted on.

I want to rev part of our version number based on this, so a developer can tell if a build was conducted on a dev machine, a production build box, et. al.

I think using $(COMPUTERNAME) would be a good start, but how might I do the comparison?

**Example:**

3.2.0.416 -> The 0 would tell us that the build is an unofficial dev build.

3.2.1.417 -> The 1 would tell us that this build was produced on our QA CI box.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I found this article to be a good starting point ([Setting .NET Assembly Version with Jenkins and TFS](http://manicai.tumblr.com/post/16885262017/setting-net-assembly-version-with-jenkins-and-tfs))

Comment: Why set the version number on any build other  than the production build server? Why are you building on 2 different boxes? Dev i get but why do you have a "QA CI Server" and a production build box?

Comment: I'm just using that as a convoluted example. I wouldn't take stock in that as it's not the meat of the question. But to answer you directly, we have CI, but our production builds are done manually because some additional steps are required that we don't currently have automated. This is largely irrelevant however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a property based on the MachineName.
2. Use that property to update the AssemblyInfo.cs file(s) before
   building.

I have "SubVersionRevision" below, but just use an alternate syntax to get the TFS version (from the link you have in your original post)........

The Crux of the solution is : setting and using "MyCustomProperty001"

```
<Choose>


    <When Condition=" '$(Computername)'=='MyDevMachine' ">               
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty001>0</MyCustomProperty001>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>

    <When Condition=" '$(Computername)'=='MyQaMachine' ">

        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty001>1</MyCustomProperty001>
        </PropertyGroup>

    </When>

    <Otherwise>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty001>9</MyCustomProperty001>

        </PropertyGroup>        

    </Otherwise>

</Choose>
```

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<SvnVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ToolPath="$(SVNToolPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="MySubVersionRevision" />
</SvnVersion>


<FileUpdate Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)"
Regex="AssemblyFileVersion\(&quot;(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"
ReplacementText="AssemblyFileVersion(&quot;$1.$2.$(MyCustomProperty001).$(SubVersionRevision)" />
```